# What have happened to LTSP in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ltsp

I wanted to install LTSP on Ubuntu 12.04, but I can't find any Ubuntu 12.04 alternative CD's, were LTSP are normally an install option.

Have LTSP been dropped?

Or should it somehow be installed from the desktop or server edition?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking Server Fault to replace Google. (Google: `LTSP Ubuntu 12.04 download` and you get exactly what Janne posted below.) This does not meet the minimum standard of research/effort for *professional* system/network administration. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the alternate download options are well hidden in the main Ubuntu site.

Get the alternate install CD from [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/).